# Grammar book for Russian B2-C1 exam preparation

Tags: grammar, russian

I would like to review Russian grammar for passing the entry exams at a Russian university. Can you please suggest books where I can find structured chapters on Russian grammar?

**UPDATE**

I can fluently speak and understand Russian speech as I am from a post-USSR country, but would like to improve grammar as well as I would appreciate if you could suggest exercise books of intermediate or advanced level. For exam I need B2-C1.

Comment: If you find any grammar books that suit your needs, it would be very helpful if you could write them up in an answer to your own question. (Answering your own questions is perfectly OK on Stack Exchange.)

Answer (score 2):

There are several books that may help you:

- John Murray & Sarah Smyth: *Intermediate Russian: A Grammar and Workbook*. Second edition. Routledge, 2013. [ISBN 9780415698245](https://www.routledge.com/Intermediate-Russian-A-Grammar-and-Workbook/Murray-Smyth/p/book/9780415698245). 276 pages. This book contains 18 chapters that consist of grammar explanations followed by grammar exercises. There is an answer key at the book at the book, which makes the book appropriate for autonomous study.
- John Dunn & Shamil Khairov: *Modern Russian Grammar Workbook*. Routledge, 2010. [ISBN 9780415425544](https://www.routledge.com/Modern-Russian-Grammar-Workbook/Dunn-Khairov/p/book/9780415425544). 226 pages. This is a book of grammar exercises in which the exercises are graded by level of difficulty. It claims to cover all levels from beginner to advanced. It has an answer key, which makes the book appropriate for autonomous study.
- Terence Wade and David Gillespie: *Russian Grammar Workbook*. Second edition. Wiley, 2013. [ISBN 978-1-118-32757-9](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Russian+Grammar+Workbook%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118327579). 272 pages. This is a book of grammar exercises (with an answer key) that can be used in conjunction with *A Comprehensive Russian Grammar* by the same authors. The grammar reference is explicitly for a "post-introductory" level, so I assume the same applies to the exercise book.
- There is also [*Da! A Practical Guide to Russian Grammar*](https://www.routledge.com/Da-A-Practical-Guide-to-Russian-Grammar/Filosofova-Sporing/p/book/9781444148787) by Tatiana Filosofova and Marion Sporing (Routledge, 2012), but this is for basic and intermediate grammar, so some of the content may be too easy.